# Store access token from Google OAuth 2.0 to access drive data from application account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am able to execute [quickstart.py](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-python)  for Google Drive using python. But how do we store the token and use it again - again for the same user without prompting user. Is their some way i can map user with access token when sending request for file on Google drive.

Answer (score 9):

There are many different `Storage` types offered by `google-api-python-client`, [some](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#storage) of which are [well](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/django#Storage) [documented](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/platforms/google_app_engine#Storage).

Some examples:

## oauth2client.file.Storage:

```
from oauth2client.file import Storage
...
storage = Storage('a_credentials_file')
storage.put(credentials)
...
credentials = storage.get()
```

## oauth2client.keyring_storage.Storage:

```
from oauth2client.keyring_storage import Storage
...
storage = Storage('application name', 'user name')
storage.put(credentials)
...
credentials = storage.get()
```

## oauth2client.appengine.StorageByKeyName:

```
from oauth2client.keyring_storage import StorageByKeyName
from oauth2client.keyring_storage import CredentialsNDBModel
...
storage = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsNDBModel, some_user_id, 'credentials')
storage.put(credentials)
...
credentials = storage.get()
```

## oauth2client.django_orm.Storage:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from oauth2client.django_orm import Storage
from your_project.your_app.models import CredentialsModel
...
user = # A User object usually obtained from request.
storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
credential = storage.get()
...
storage.put(credential)
```

Comment: I am not working on Google App Engine The script is supposed to run on server read some files and populate database based on data in those files. I just want to configure it first time i.e pasting link it browser then getting authorized  code , pasting it back to terminal .Data will always read from same user id.After dat even if script stops , when i restart it should read from storage.How to do i do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should give credit to bossylobster for a more complete answer, but based on your comment, which is precisely my setup, I've augmented the quickstart.py using the Storage class:

```
#!/usr/bin/python                                                                                                                         
import httplib2
import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage

# Copy your credentials from the console                                                                                                  
CLIENT_ID = 'PASTE_YOUR_ID'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'PASTE_YOUR_SECRET'

# Check https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes for all available scopes                                                               
OAUTH_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'

# Redirect URI for installed apps                                                                                                         
REDIRECT_URI = 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob'

# Create a credential storage object.  You pick the filename.
storage = Storage('a_credentials_file')

# Attempt to load existing credentials.  Null is returned if it fails.
credentials = storage.get()

# Only attempt to get new credentials if the load failed.
if not credentials:

    # Run through the OAuth flow and retrieve credentials                                                                                 
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)

    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
    print 'Go to the following link in your browser: ' + authorize_url
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()

    credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
    storage.put(credentials)


# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with our credentials                                                                    
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

# Use 'drive_service' for all of the API calls
```